# Extracting data from one cell in one column, and replacing text contained within a sentence in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am doing something I know can be done, but am having a difficult time figuring out the best way.

I want whatever is pasted into a certain cell, let's say C2, to replace what is contained within a sentence in A2. For example:

[image]

I want the brackets to remain around the date as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `CONCATENATE`?

Comment: I have tried using FIND, REPLACE, and different lookup functions, along with trying to copy and paste from one cell to within the text that needs to be replaced used a macro, but I'm not exactly sure how to copy and paste within text using said macro. If you look at my attached image you can see that I want the information when pasted into column C to replace the underlined information in column A "102 Date"

Comment: I know how to concatenate information, but replacing information within a text string is different

Comment: Use [REPLACE(old_text, start_num, num_chars, new_text)](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-replace-function).  A2 is the old_text. Use FIND() to get the start_num, unless you'll always know what it is.  If num_chars will vary, you'll have to FIND() the two square brackets and subtract their positions and subtract 1 from that.  New_text is C2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(A2, FIND("[",A2)+1, FIND("]",A2) - FIND("[",A2) - 1),TEXT(C2, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

**How it works:**

- Find command helps Excel to fetch exact value of 'start_ num'.
- Using Find is handy to replace variable length text, otherwise 'start_num'
  has to be counted manually, as you can read above in comments also.
- Text function converts the Date into specific format, otherwise Date
  from C2 would appear as Number within brackets.

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer.  Concise, restrained use of caps and bold,  no extraneous editorial comments.  A great improvement. I'll give it a vote.  Also, good point about using TEXT() to convert the date serial number to a formatted date.

Comment: Nice to hear from you @Bandersnatch, it always encourage me to do better. Have nice time.

Comment: Hello Rajesh, I very much appreciate your assistance. However, it seems as though the formula only works if A2 remains a reference? When I past your formula directly into A2, the value returned is 0, but if I paste it into A1, then it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you can't overwrite A2 because it's used in the formula. You can put it anywhere except A2 or C2.

Comment: @RajeshS so the end goal was to be able to replace both values, "102 date, and "agency," so from: 

Agent effective [102 date] with [agency].

Comment: I have tried =SUBSTITUTE(A17,MID(A17,FIND("[",A17)+1,FIND("]",A17)-FIND("[",A17)-1),TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy"))&REPLACE("agency",34,6,C6)

as well as

=SUBSTITUTE(A18,MID(A18,FIND("[",A18)+1,FIND("]",A18)-FIND("[",A18)-1),TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&"] "&SUBSTITUTE(A18,MID(A18,FIND(".",A18)-7,FIND("]",A18)-FIND("[",A18)+10),TEXT(C6," ")))

and end up with

Agent effective [03/08/2018] with [agency].agencyCITIZENS SECURITIES INC

and

Agent effective [03/08/2018] Agent effective [102 date] with [CITIZENS SECURITIES INC] with [agency].

I either can get rid of the duplicates, or proper format