# Dynamic replacement of text within a text string

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

So I'm asking one more time because I'm very close to being where I want with this.

I have already received some help which I am very grateful for, but just a bit more would be much appreciated!

I am trying to be able to paste data into a cell, which will automatically populate within a text string in another cell. As you can see in my image, I am able to replace data in the first field, however I can't seem to figure out how to be able to replace the data also in the second field that is highlighted.

[image]

The formula I am using so far is:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A17,MID(A17,FIND("[",A17)+1,FIND("]",A17)-FIND("[",A17)-1),TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

Essentially I want to be able to paste data into the C column fields, and have them populate in the A column text strings.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!

The end goal is to have 9 rows of notes, that can be copied from cells in column C, and populate data within the individual text strings. The image provided shows where I want to be able to quickly paste information, that populates in corresponding location in column A, I have my references pasted down lower in column A:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8cBj.png)

Using:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A21,MID(A21,FIND("[",A21)+1,FIND("]",A21)-FIND("[",A21)-1),TEXT(C8,"state")),"104 date",C4,1)

I go from:

Ordered [state] appointments effective [104 date], updated 103/104.

I end up with:

Ordered [PA] appointments effective [43167], updated 103/104.

I know the date is simply out of format but I haven't been able to get "mm/dd/yyyy" to work correctly in this formula, whereas in this formula:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A17,MID(A17,FIND("[",A17)+1,FIND("]",A17)-FIND("[",A17)-1),TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")),"agency",C6,1)

It works just fine:

Before: Agent effective [102 date] with [agency].

After: Agent effective [03/15/2018] with [CITIZENS SECURITIES INC].

Hopefully that helps clarify any questions. Formulas are all I'm looking for. Macros would be nice but I don't know VBA.

Comment: (1) Please try harder to explain your problem clearly.  You should link to [your previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1302045/150988 "Extracting data from one cell in one column, and replacing text contained within a sentence in another column") for reference, but this question should be comprehensible on its own.  (2) Don’t try to clarify your question by editing somebody else’s answer (or in comments); [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  (3) Do you want a worksheet formula answer, or do you want a VBA (“macro”) answer? (3a) You say that you want … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  to be able to have data in one cell modify another cell.  Phrased that way, that’s impossible with formulas.  (It might help if you explained exactly what you are accomplishing with the formula you have now.)  (3b) You present a formula (with no explanation), but then tag your question [vba] and [macro], but not [worksheet-function].  Please make up your mind.  (Have you even tried VBA?  If so, please post *that* code.)  (4) What is the scope of the problem?  (4a) Do you absolutely positively guarantee that the sentences in Column A will never have more than two fields,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  or might there be more? (4b) For every sentence in Column A, does the solution need to check every value in Column C?  (For example, might `A17` say “Opened account number [account number] at [bank].”, where the values for “account number” and “bank” are in cells `C144` and `C142`?)  (4c) Do you have some way of *finding* the appropriate values in Column C (e.g., use `C142` for “[bank]” because cell `C141` says “Paste bank HERE”), or do you need help with that, too? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just nest the `SUBSTITUTE` in the `SUBSTITUTE`.

For example

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A17,MID(A17,FIND("[",A17)+1,FIND("]",A17)-FIND("[",A17)-1),TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")),"[agency]","SOMETHING",1)
```

Comment: I was able to make this work for when the date comes before the agency in the text string, but why does it not work if the date comes after the portion of the text string i'm trying to replace? I appreciate the help

Comment: any comment @shinjijai? I'm so close!

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of the issue?

Comment: I did up above, showing the result I am getting with each formula, before/after, and also a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish overall, which I'm very close!

Comment: Looking at your example, the substitution worked. `43167` is the serialized number for the date of `March 8, 2018`. You forgot to do `TEXT(C4,"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

Comment: when I do that as:


=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A21,MID(A21,FIND("[",A21)+1,FIND("]",A21)-FIND("[",A21)-1),TEXT(C8,"state"),TEXT(c4,"mm/dd/yyyy")))


it tells me too few arguments have been entered, this is where i'm stuck! I do know that is the serialized number, just can't get it to convert over to proper date format after trying many things

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `,1` after the `TEXT(C4,"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: I have tried that:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A21,MID(A21,FIND("[",A21)+1,FIND("]",A21)-FIND("[",A21)-1),TEXT(C8,"state"),TEXT(c4,"mm/dd/yyyy",1))

still says I'm entereing too few arguments

Comment: I copied and paste your formulate into a blank Excel sheet, you're not closing your brackets properly, and also you need to fill in the "date" you're trying to replace: Using this: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A21,MID(A21,FIND("[",A21)+1,FIND("]",A21)-FIND("[",A21)-1),TEXT(C8,"state")),<OLD TEXT>,TEXT(c4,"mm/dd/yyyy")))` try to fix it to what you need.

Comment: ahhhh! Thank you so much Shinjijai! I knew it was close Thank you so much!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Shinjijai 's answer will work, but I thought I would provide a different way of looking at it. I don't know what your end state looks like, but you could also do this with a table and a bit smaller formula.

[image: Effective Date Table]

The table above has the following formula in Cell E2:

```
=[Agent] & " effective 102 Date "&TEXT([102 Date],"mm/dd/yy")&", effective 104 Date "&TEXT([104 Date],"mm/dd/yy")&" with "&[Agency]
```

Putting this in a table allows you to use structured references (like "Agent" instead of A2). The formula is just a combination of predetermined text and the cell references.

I don't know if you need both 102 and 104 dates in the same formula, but you could easily break this formula in half and put end-state 102 info in Col E and end-state 104 in Col F.

With a table, you could also use data validation in your Agency column, so you could have drop down combo boxes instead of typing in agency names.

Just wanted to share a different option. Hope you find a great answer!

Comment: I appreciate the input, however I cannot have this in table format

Answer (score 0):

I must misunderstand the problem given the answers above, but it appears that you want a text string with prompts for the varying data that goes into them. Then, when the actual data is entered in the data block, you want that to replace those prompts.

The easy way to do that is to have a formula that uses text for the stock of it with two `IF()` functions in the places where the prompts/data go. The `IF()` functions look to see if the entry area has entries for each and put the entry into the string if so, and the prompt if not so.

Very simple formulas. Look something like:

```
="Agent effective ["&IF($C$2<>"",$C$2,IF($C$4<>"",$C$4,"102 date"))&"] with ["&IF($C$6<>"",$C$6,"agency"&"]"
```

All on automatic. Change for you when the desired data is entered. Or cleared, then they change back to the prompts.